# How to make correct S4 Class declaration for a package

Tags: r, rstudio, r-s4

I am creating a personal package with some S4 classes. When I run the `Build and Reload` button in the Rstudio IDE I get the next message.

```
in method for ‘checkNewItems’ with signature ‘"webSource"’: no definition for class "webSource"
```

The Class declaration `webSource` is in a different file where the `checkNewItems` method is and I am guessing that is the reason why I am getting that message. In the source code that I have makes more sense to have the class declaration in other place rather than next to the methods `checkNewItems`.

Which is the idiomatic workaround that R programmers use for this?

Also, from the point of view of the `Lazyloading` that R uses I assumed that this should not happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should export your class. In your `namespace file` you add this:

```
exportClasses(webSource)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of that. Let me check.